# Hide popover on body click only if already visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hiding a div (for example `#popover`) on click is easy:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#trigger").click(function(e) {
        $("#popover").toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('#popover, #popover *')) {
            $("#popover").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

But isn't this function fired every time the user uses a `click`? (Which does not make sense for me). Can I somehow limit this function to fire only if `#popover` is already visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you can try using `$(document).one(function(e) {...});` every time you show `#example`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var didBindToBody = false;

    function closePopOverOnBodyClick() {
      didBindToBody = true;

      $(document).one('click', function(e) {             
          if (!$(e.target).is('#popover, #popover *')) {
              $("#popover").hide();
          }
          else {
              closePopOverOnBodyClick();
          }

          didBindToBody = false;
      });
    }

    $("#trigger").click(function(e) {
        $("#popover").toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();

        if (!didBindToBody && $("#popover").is(":visible")) {
            closePopOverOnBodyClick();
        }  
    });

    closePopOverOnBodyClick();
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avYKdY?editors=001)</kbd>

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion. The `$(document).one()` does not fire at all, but I am not able to find your mistake. Feel free to check this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVvKGN

Comment: Thanks a lot for this improvement! I am sorry, but there is still one problem left. Using `.one` you target the first click. As soon as this click is inside the `#popver` you will disable the ability to hide via clicking the body.

Comment: @MarianRick just a case of making the binding again. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
$(document).click(function(e) {

    if (!$('#example').is(":visible")) {
        return false;
    } else if (!$(e.target).is('#popover, .login-panel *')) {
        $("#popover").hide();
    }
});
```

Or you could combine the two conditionals into one, just thought I'd keep it separate for readability and to make my suggestion easier to spot.

Comment: I am interested in creating a string, like `function(){ show element function() { hide element only while active} }`. Using your example the document would still check every time if the element is visible, wouldn't it?

Comment: yes, that's right, the code in the answer will fire for every single click on the page but I just took the example from the question and used that.